# dijit.byId doesn't work on IE8 with dojo.addOnLoad

Tags: internet-explorer-8, dojo

When I load this script with IE8, I've got exception `Object does not support this property or method`.  But it works with other browsers.

I use dijit 1.3.1 and I don't understand.

```
dojo.addOnLoad(init);
var DG;
var datas;

function init(){
    DG = dijit.byId("DG");
}
```

I've had parseOnload: true but it changes anything.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dojo/dojo.js"
        djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
</script>
```

Comment: In which line does IE throw the exception? And are there any Details in it?

Comment: IE throws the exception at line DG = dijit.byId("DG"); character 5 and the exact error is "Object doesn't support this property or method", no more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This migth probably not fix the problem, but the function `init()` is used before it was declared.
Try this:

```
    var DG;
    var datas;

    function init(){
        DG = dijit.byId("DG");
    }

    dojo.addOnLoad(init);
```

Does it work?

Comment: can you provide us with a fiddle?

Comment: I created a fiddle but it's difficult to show exactly like i use http://jsfiddle.net/pfd5k/4/

Comment: According to the [API-documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/) (V1.3), `dijit.layout.ContentPane` doesn't own a method called `load`. Where do you got this from? What is it supposed to do? You can watch the error dissappear in you fiddle by simply outcommenting the call `DG.load(...);`

Comment: Could it be that you mean [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) by `jQuery`? Anyway, tell me what you want to do here especially. What confuses me is the fact, that you apparently try to load css-code into the innerHTML of the `div`-container.

Comment: In fact, DG is a oaf.widget.DataGrid wich is a widget of Orange France Telecom. The idea is to load the content of an url (in my example CSS but in fact, it is html) into my widget.

It works with others browsers. I think the addOnLoad doesn't wait the loading of all the page and the dijit.byYd doesn't work because dijit isn't fully loaded. I f add a setTimeOut to init with 1 second, IE8 doesn't throw an error.

Comment: It's exaclty the same problem as http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Debugging-IE8-td103320.html

Comment: One last desperate attempt could be, to wrap your `dojo.addOnLoad()` in an other `dojo.addOnLoad()` while doing everything else in the 1st-lvl cascade... But this will  probably not work either..But I guess you already experimented with `dojo.addOnLoad` in combination with `window.onload`, didn't you?

Comment: It works but i think it's the same workaround as set a setTimeout, the loading is slower and object dijit is fully loaded.

Comment: its similar, but not the same (should be faster than a sec.). but it works, yay :D

Comment: the inner `addOnLoad()` will [wait until the package dependencies are complete](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/addOnLoad.html). I dont completely understand how exactly that works, but as long as it works... hope it helped you..