# dojo.addonLoad() doesn't seem to work with IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dojo

as stated by the above, I am using IE 9 as the IE browser and Firefox 16 and Chrome.

Apparently this block of code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    dojo.addOnLoad(initQuery);
});
```

does not seem to load when the browser reaches the page yet other browsers work wonderfully. is there a work around it? I use dojo packages but will be open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax looks like an odd mix of jQuery and dojo to me. I don't see why you shouldn't be using something simpler like

```
require("dojo/ready", function(ready){
    ready(function(){
        initQuery();
    });
});
```

This is based on the example on in the dojo docs.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/addOnLoad.html

Answer (score 1):

Nick Roth's answer is a good one, instead the missing brackets :

```
require(["dojo/ready"], function(ready){
    ready(function(){
        initQuery();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping it in another `dojo.addOnLoad()` which worked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365287/dijit-byid-doesnt-work-on-ie8-with-dojo-addonload/13374297#13374297) (see comments) or experiment with setTimeOut a little if you don't mind the ineffectivness :/

Comment: I saw that question but the problem here is that the dojo.addOnLoad ain't working in IE, not even the traditional javascript `<body onLoad="init()">` method works.

Comment: okay, can you provide an fiddle or sth. to reproduce the issue? Did you declare `initQuery()` before the statement?

Comment: i know you meant good but its not that simple as not declaring the function... the initQuery is in js file i included. I tested on Chrome or Firefox and it worked. I can't reproduce the issue on jsfiddle with a simple `<body onLoad="init()">` method but the initQuery() could not even print an alert statement i put inside the first line of it.